# Giving different colors to the dots that are in different intervals on a scatter plot in R

Tags: r, plot, statistics, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I am a beginner in R and would like to give different colors to the dots in my scatter plot, between 0 -> 0.4, 0.4 ->0.8 and 0.8 -> 1 in my x-axis.
i have googled a lot but was not able to find hints for the solution.

i am using this code for the plot :

```
ggplot(xlim=1, ylim=1,)+geom_point(data=df,aes(x1,y1))+
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = x0, y0 = y0 ,r = r,colour=cb), data = circ_kv) +
  coord_fixed(xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,1))
```

all help or hints are very much appreciated!

[this is the scatter plot i am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zORb1.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to color the dots in vertical stripes (only look at x) or do you want to color them, if they are between two circles (look at x and y)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1337)

data <- tibble(
  x = runif(300),
  y = runif(300)
)
  
data %>%
  mutate(
    # distance to origin
    r = sqrt(x**2 + y**2),
    r_group = case_when(
      r < 0.4 ~ "group 1",
      r < 0.8 ~ "group 2",
      r < 1.0 ~ "group 3"
    )
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,y, color = r_group)) +
    geom_point() +
    coord_fixed()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>